# NumPy ImportError in python - Dll load failed

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've installed the latest version of numpy from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2/) for python 3.2 on 64-bit Windows Vista for use with matplotlib. However, when I try to import matplotlib, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

This occurs on the `from . import multiarray` line in numpy's *init*.py file

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are most likely using a 64bit Python with a 32bit numpy or vice versa. Make sure both have the same bitness.

Unless you need 64bit python for some reason it's usually a good idea to stay with 32bit as you might have to compile some binary python packages manually since 32bit binary packages are much more common.