# Memory Error with half-full memory

Tags: python, memory, numpy

I have a well built project in Python 2.7 using Windows7. It works well before today, and I just running it without modifying it for weeks.

Today, when I open it and try to run it, it gives me some ImportError which says `numpy` and `wx` package are not valid Win32 applications. So I re-install these packages (32-bit versions). Then it is executable.

However, the thing is getting even weird, it keeps giving memory error. I was watching the task manager, and can obviously see that when the error pops, the memory is just half-full.

May I know how I can make it works properly?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I've tried to install 64 bit version of Numpy to replace the 32 bit one. However, the memory error pops again.

**EDIT2:**

Following is the trace back numpy import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\user\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\State Machine Version 4.0\main.py", line 9, in <module>
import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 154, in <module>  
import add_newdocs    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module> 
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module> 
from type_check import *  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>  
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
import multiarray 
  ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

**EDIT3:**

I've installed 32-bit numpy again. Now the memory error is back. The trace back is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\State Machine Version 4.0\main.py", line 55, in <module>
    portfolio = Portfolio(portfolio_path, recovery_tree_path, tree_rule_path, output_path, history_length, horizon, simulation_number, simulation_mode, adjustment_mode, adjustment_node_list, segmentation_flag, segmentation_variable)
  File "C:\Users\user\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\State Machine Version 4.0\PortfolioClass.py", line 131, in __init__
    self.LoadFromCSV()
  File "C:\Users\user\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\State Machine Version 4.0\PortfolioClass.py", line 139, in LoadFromCSV
    self.load_accounts()       
  File "C:\Users\user\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\State Machine Version 4.0\PortfolioClass.py", line 217, in load_accounts
    acc = Account(account_id, vintage, sale_balance, LPAPerc2, Con_Score_Pre, Predicted_Contact_Type_ITC, thresholds, cost)
  File "C:\Users\user\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\State Machine Version 4.0\AccountClass.py", line 153, in __init__
    self._account_monthly_revenues = np.zeros((self._parent._simulation_number, self._parent._horizon))
MemoryError
```

Comment: if you are using a 32 bit version the maximum usable memory by a thread is about 4GB (on Windows it is less than this)

Comment: You might have had a 64bit version of Python installed and you changed it to 32bit. That would explain the invalid packages *and* the memory error.

Comment: @SaulloCastro I've installed 64 bit versions as well, the error pops again...

Comment: @ChangeMyName do you have both the 32 and the 64 bit versions installed? If yes, are you sure you are using the 64 bit? It would be really helpfull if you posted the relevant part of your code and the error traceback here...

Comment: @SaulloCastro Please have a look at edit 2, I post the numpy import error in it. I currently uninstalled all versions of numpy and re-installed 64 bit version numpy after that. Edit 2 is the error I've got.

Comment: @ChangeMyName is your Windows 7 64 bit? If it is 32 bit, this would explain the error...

Comment: @SaulloCastro My system is Windows7 64-bit

Comment: please provide stack trace for memory error

Comment: possible duplicate of [NumPy ImportError in python - Dll load failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404269/numpy-importerror-in-python-dll-load-failed)

Comment: @qarma after reinstall the numpy package, the only error I have is the numpy import error.

Comment: see linked question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11404269/705086

Comment: @qarma Thanks for the link. I've read the thread before. It turns out that my numpy version and Python version and OS version all are 64-bit.

Comment: @qarma I've put 32-bit version mumpy back and the memory error is back as well. Please read Edit 3.

Comment: what are the values for `(self._parent._simulation_number, self._parent._horizon)` ?

Comment: @qarma the values are 10 and 120

Comment: and does `np.zeroes((10,120))` work? if that doesn't work, please edit your answer top to bottom, because that's the core problem.