# wxPython import error with Windows install

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, wxpython, importerror

I have installed Python 3.4 and wxPython Phoenix on Windows 10.  I go into Eclipse and add wxPython to the external libs in my project, but when I try to import it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\linus\workspace\MiCS 1.2\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\wx\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I did some searching and tinkering and still can't figure out what's causing it.  It shouldn't be the msvcp or msvcr DLLs as I have Office running just fine (or is that an incorrect assumption?)  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: This maybe similar to question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11404318/5781248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you install wxpython?

As of now, the top page of the official site has wxpython 3.0 only for python27. So, I suspect you might not have installed it properly.

If you have your python34 at C:/Python34 then, cd to C:/Python34/Scripts first so that we make sure to use the pip for this python.

According to this post (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-dev/LmGIrQyh7jc), try

`pip install -U --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix`

This should find the corresponding whl file for your python version and CPU architecture.

Or, you could manually download whl file at http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/

If you have 32 bit Python34, then look for ******-cp34-none-win32.whl

and simply do:

`pip install path/to/the/whl/that/you/just/downloaded/wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev1839+4ecd949-cp34-none-win32.whl`

After this, if you can `import wx` in the normal cmd then the problem should be coming from eclipse.